# How do I create a bootable Ubuntu partition on a MacBook Air?

Tags: system-installation, macintosh

How do I create a bootable Ubuntu partition on a MacBook Air? I want to be able to boot to Mac OS and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The general way is to use a utility like [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) or [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to create a live usb, partition your drive using Disk Utility, (depending on your macbook, install a boot manager like [rEFInd](https://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/)), and finally boot to the usb and install Ubuntu. Be careful not erase your boot drive, backing up your data is strongly recommended.

This guide appears to be comprehensive and up-to-date so I would highly recommend following it if it's your first time installing linux on a mac. https://linuxnewbieguide.org/how-to-install-linux-on-a-macintosh-computer/#Using_Etcher_to_burn_your_ISO_image_to_a_USB_stick

Note: Depending on what year MacBook you have, you may have to deal with the new  T2 chip which would prevent you from running anything but macOS. I would recommend this [article](https://linuxnewbieguide.org/how-to-install-linux-on-a-macintosh-computer/) for reference, though the issue is covered in the linuxnewbieguide above.